# How to automatically add the values inserted by user in the text fields then display total on div?

Tags: javascript

I currently have this html code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addmore()">Add More Field</a>
<div id="addmore">
<ul class="jcform" id="countme">
  <li><input id="name" class="form-control" name="cname[]" type="text" value=""/></li>
  <li><input id="score" class="form-control" name="cscore[]" type="text" value=""/></li>
</ul>
</div>
 Total: <div id="displaytotalscore"></div>
```

Below is my javascript:

```
function removeme(numm) {
 document.getElementById('remove'+numm+'').remove();
}
function addmore() {
  var top_level_div = document.getElementById('addmore');
  var count = top_level_div.getElementsByTagName('ul').length;
  var ul = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.className = 'jcform';
  ul.id = 'remove' + count;
  var tbl1 = '<li><input class="form-control" id="field1" name="cname[]" type="text" 
              value=""/></li>  
              <li><input class="form-control" id="fieldpoints1" name="cpoints[]" 
              type="text" value=""/></li>
             <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeme(' + count + ')">
              Removed</a></li>';
   ul.innerHTML = tbl1;

   document.getElementById('addmore').appendChild(ul)
}
```

What i want to achieve is, when a user enters values in the text fields id="score", i want to display the total sum in the div id="displaytotalscore". I am not sure how to use onchange event here.

Ok here's the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/41fw2c4x/

Comment: If you need help on a concrete case, please host your code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please remove unnecessary code and show us what you already tried. Also, a fiddle would be nice.

Comment: bind a keyup function to the score fields.  Your addMore function doesn't seem to add any extra score fields?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/41fw2c4x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector("#score").addEventListener("change", function(){
  document.querySelector("#displaytotalscore").textContent = this.value;
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="addmore()">Add More Field</a>
<ul class="jcform" id="countme">
  <li><input id="name" class="form-control" name="cname[]" type="text" value=""/></li>
  <li><input id="score" class="form-control" name="cscore[]" type="text" value=""/></li>
</ul>

 Total: <div id="displaytotalscore"></div>
```

This shows the basic working of the `onchange` event. User fills in a score in the input with `id` `score`. When this loses focus (blurs) it will invoke the onchange event setting the score to the div using the property `textContent`.

Updated with your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/41fw2c4x/2/

```js
function addmore() {
    var top_level_div = document.getElementById('addmore');
    var count = top_level_div.getElementsByTagName('ul').length;
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.className = 'jcform';
    ul.id = 'remove' + count;
    var tbl1 = '<li>Name <input class="form-control" id="field1" name="cname[]" type="text" value=""/></li>  <li>Score <input class="form-control" id="fieldpoints1" name="cpoints[]" type="text" value=""/></li><li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeme(' + count + ')">Removed</a></li>';
    ul.innerHTML = tbl1;

    document.getElementById('addmore').appendChild(ul)
}

//my solution
    document.querySelector("#addmore").addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
      if (e.target && e.target.tagName == "INPUT" && e.target.name == "cpoints[]")
      {
          updateScore();
      }
    }, false);

function updateScore()
{
   var score = 0;
   Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[name='cpoints[]']"), function(element){
      score += !isNaN(parseInt(element.value)) ? parseInt(element.value) : 0; //when not a digit add 0, or ignore.
   });
   document.querySelector("#displaytotalscore").textContent = score;
          
}

function removeme(numm) {
    document.getElementById('remove' + numm + '').parentElement.removeChild(document.getElementById('remove' + numm + ''));
    updateScore();
}

//solution end
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="addmore()"> Add More Field</a> 
<div id="addmore">
    <ul class="jcform" id="countme">
        <li>Name
            <input id="name" class="form-control" name="cname[]" type="text" value="" />
        </li>
        <li>Score
            <input id="score" class="form-control" name="cpoints[]" type="text" value="" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>Total:
<div id="displaytotalscore"></div>
```

This adds an `keyup` event to the main div (`addmore`). Every time it detect an input element with the name `cpoints[]`, it will iterate over all inputs with that name. Sum the total amount and display it in the div. It ignores values other than numbers by assigning the value `0`. It checks if something is a number with the `isNaN` method.

Why did I switch to the `keyup` event? It allows me to use only one event, instead of adding an onchange event for every input. Why not set an onchange event on the div then? div don't support onchange events, so we need a different approach, in this case the keyup.

Comment: Thank you! but one problem, when i click on the remove button, the total sum retains.

Comment: @user3835444, relocated the score calculation inside a function. When you click on the `removed` link it will also run `updateScore` to show the correct value. Are you a beginner?

Comment: @user3835444, thought so, because that last question was really simple to implement. Hope you're learning from this :-). It's nice to puzzle it out by yourself.